# Comparing the usage of というのは and ということは

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

As far as I know, both というのは and ということは can be used to give definition/explanation.

> 留学する**ということは**、海外で勉強するということだ。
>
> ユートピア**というのは**理想郷の意だ

And are also used to make inferences.

> ご意見がない**ということは**賛成ということですね。
>
> ヨーロッパに留学する**というのは**、英語が第2外国語ということです。

Here comes the question. Are というのは and ということは totally interchangeable?

For example,

> 何事も最後までやり抜く(ということは/というのは)何事も決して放棄しないということだ.

Answer (score 3):

I think they are interchangeable except one case. When a noun is placed before them, only というのは is used like ユートピアというのは理想郷の意だ, 勉強というのは役に立つものだ and so on.