# Understanding the pattern 「名詞1+っての+名詞2」

Tags: grammar

> 「やー……あたしもねえ、狙われたままの生活**っての**窮屈だし、封印できるもんならしてもらって構わなかったんだけど……やっぱ駄目っぽいわ。なんかごめんね、無駄足踏ませちゃって」

Source: https://syosetu.org/novel/9452/63.html

I am familiar with the grammar pattern 「名詞1+という+名詞2」. But this っての／というの baffles me. How can というの connect two nouns? Shouldn’t we just say って?

Comment: This is basically the same as ってのは

Answer (score 3, accepted):

っての is short for っていうの or というの, and here it is used to describe an important implication/characteristic of something. Here the topic marker は is omitted after の.

> 狙われたままの生活っての窮屈だし、
> = 狙われたままの生活というのは窮屈だし、
>
> Life with someone on my back is (generally) uncomfortable, and ...

See:

- [Providing definitions/explanations with というのは　～　のこと/ということだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24092/5010)
- [Comparing the usage of というのは and ということは](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68385/5010)